# Why the class button does not work the same as the kv file button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, kivy

When clicking on the button generated by the *.KV file, the buttons are generated in a grid (2). When clicking on the button of the "Create" class, the buttons are generated superimposed.

How do I solve the overlay buttons problem?

**test.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return Window()

class Window(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cols = 2
        self.col_force_default = True
        self.col_default_width = 200
        self.row_force_default = True
        self.row_default_height = 40

        self.add_widget((Button(text="Create",
                       on_release=Window.addWidget)))

    def addWidget(self):
        count = 0
        while count < 10:
            count = count + 1
            self.add_widget(Button(text=str(count)))
Test().run()
```

---

**test.kv**

```
<Window>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            on_release:root.addWidget()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your python code the line:

```
on_release=Window.addWidget)))
```

arranges for `Window.addWidget()` to be called when the `Button` is released. When an `on_release` is specified, the `Button` that was release is passed as an argument to the specified method. So, when the `Button` is released, the actual call is executed as:

```
Window.addWidget(button_instance)
```

Now the `addWidget()` method of your `Window` class is an instance method, meaning that it expects the first argument passed to it is the `self` (the instance of the `Window` class). Since you are not calling it properly as an instance method, the passed in `button_instance` is mistaken for the `Window` class instance, and the created `Buttons` are added to the `button_instance` instead of the `Window` instance.

You can fix this by correctly calling the `addWidget()` method like this:

```
on_release=lambda button: self.addWidget())))
```

The `lambda` is just to remove the added `button_instance` argument.

A different fix is to add `*args` to the `addWidget()`, like this:

```
def addWidget(self, *args):
```

Then the `on_release` line is simpler:

```
on_release=self.addWidget)))
```